# Use Python with NumPy in Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I currently try to call a Python function in Matlab. Everything is working, until I try to use any standard library in my Python function. In my case its NumPy, that shall be used. Instead of the output, Matlab is giving me the Error:

Error using _distributor_init> (line 34)
Python Error: ImportError: DLL load failed: the modul can not be found.

_distributor_init.py is part of NumPy and line 33/34 is:

```
with RTLD_for_MKL():
    from . import _mklinit
```

Does anyone know how to connect Python with NumPy to Matlab?

Comment: NumPy is not part of the Python standard library

Comment: I did not know. However, In the Python Code, I imported it and I have installed it in my Anaconda environment.

Comment: Find out what environment MATLAB is using. That support is why you're paying the big bucks.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pyversion` and make sure it is pointing to the appropriate anaconda environment bin. And obviously that numpy is installed in that python environment.